XMPP discovery and resource binding
I have a question regarding issuing disco(very) request. Say I have a user1@mydomain that wants to initiate a chat with user2@mydomain. After creating a chat and registering all handlers, I would like to call:
chat->disco()->getDiscoInfo(targetAddress.full(), "", this, 0);

but - targetAdress will not necessary have "resource" part, e.g. it will not be user2@mydomain/mylabpc1 and thus, some discovery info, like <feature var="urn:xmpp:message-correct:0" /> will not be present.
So, is there a way user initiating a chat can "know" when is safe to issue disco - via some subscription or something else?
